# html 5 and mysql 

Tags: android, mysql, html

I'm trying to develop android web apps using html 5.I'm using dreamviewer 5 with Jquery.

but i want to access hosted mysql database. how can i do this from html 5?

Is this a  good way to pass parameters to php and access mysql? or any appropriate way

to do this.

many thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use web services in PHP to  transfer data data.

Some of them are :

**XML _RPC**

**SOAP**

**REST**

Here are some examples :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/267023/Send-and-receive-json-between-android-and-php

http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-series-from-sql-php-to-xml-json-to-android-listview/

Comment: thanks for your reply.i got your point. Is this secure way? any 3rd party can access the web services? how can i prevent that?

Comment: We can add authentication and encryption functionality in web service.

Comment: go through this link http://wso2.org/library/2814 . We can also make access_token system

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use MySQL directly from HTML5. I suggest you calling a web address which can return you whatever you want to display on android app.

Comment: Thankz for reply. you mean get data through php the file or use web service or something??

Comment: Yes you should definitely connect database and prepare output in server side with PHP or other server side technologies.

Comment: Yeah it will work perfectly using MySql with php web service and having HTML5 client

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP or any server technologies on your web server and using JQuery on hosted application i-e by using post() or get() functions of JQuery.